# End-to-end Installation Script for Solr 6 on Ubuntu 16.x

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, scripts, java, solr

I did a bit of digging around and only found a handful of long procedures like say the one on [Digital Ocean for Ubuntu 14](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-solr-on-ubuntu-14-04), which actually is pretty good. But there is still an awful lot of things to keep in mind.
I dug up the usual sources, but found no script that would actually automate the entire process from Java through install to core creation.

I wrote an [end-to-end Solr installer script for RedHat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41488812/install-script-for-solr-6-on-redhat/41488813#41488813) and was wondering if there is one for Ubuntu I may have missed? Or should I actually devote some time and write it myself?

Answer (score 3):

Check out Geerling Guy's Ansible role for Solr:
https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-solr

It does everything you want, with very little effort.

That being said, here's what I used to run before I started using Ansible. This works for both Solr 5 and 6 on Ubuntu 14, Ubuntu 16, and RHEL 6.

I never bothered to include anything to do with cores since that's beyond the scope of what I would normally be doing in my role, but you should be able to find that fairly easily, and append it:

```
#!/bin/bash -eu    

[ $EUID -eq 0 ] || {
    echo "This script requires root or sudo"
    exit 1
}

# Solr depends on Java
apt-get install -y default-jre || sudo yum install -y java-headless

# Look up most recent version at http://archive.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/
SOLR_VERSION='6.4.2'

wget "http://archive.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/$SOLR_VERSION/solr-$SOLR_VERSION.tgz"

# Extract just the install script from the bundle
tar xzf "solr-$SOLR_VERSION.tgz" "solr-$SOLR_VERSION/bin/install_solr_service.sh" --strip-components=2

./install_solr_service.sh solr-$SOLR_VERSION.tgz
```